# Algorithm for the Planarization of a non-planar Graph

Tags: graph, boost-graph, planar-graph

Is there a popular algorithm for the planarization of a non-planar graph.

I'm currently planning to implement a Orthogonal Planar Layout algorithm for undirected graphs in Boost ( Boost Graph Library ). BGL has an implementation to check the planarity of an undirected graph ( Boyer-Myrvold Planarity Testing ) and I plan to use the planar embedding returned by this method to do an orthogonal layout.

But I'm not sure what should be done if the input graph is non-planar. Should I do something with the Kuratowski sub-graph returned in such a scenario to make the graph planar.

A Google Search on "Planarization of non-planar graphs" returns multiple research papers. I'm not sure where to start.

Answer (score 1):

There are exponentially many $K_5$ and $K_{3,3}$ subgraphs of a $K_n$, never mind minors, so treating them directly isn't terribly efficient.  I suggest flipping through said research papers to learn a bit about how other people approach the problem.  You should pay attention to properties that (a) give sensible solutions and (b) sound like graphs that interest you.