# Planar embedding for non-planar graphs in Boost Graph Library?

Tags: c++, boost, graph, graph-drawing, planar-graph

The boost graph library seems to have planar embedding algorithms implemented for maximally planar graphs. Does it also have anything implemented to *planarize* a non-planar graph? Hopefully something that minimizes crossings.

I have found that the [Open Graph Drawing Framework](http://www.ogdf.net/doc-ogdf/classogdf_1_1_planarization_layout.html) has some planarization code, but I'd rather use something in boost if it exists.

This [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421133/algorithm-for-the-planarization-of-a-non-planar-graph) asks something similar, but not directly about the existence of such an algorithm in boost.